# JavaFX - save canvas to png file

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, png

I've created a simple drawing program which just basically prints pictures on a canvas by choosing from 3 pictures and then the user can save the image that he created and open a previous image , the program works perfectly good , but I'm facing a problem :

- when I save the image , the image is not being saved as a png ,it's
  rather getting saved as a file (not sure though) but even when it's
  not being saved as a png , the image is getting saved and the user
  can open it and it opens as it was saved.

Here's the code :

```
package sample;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Stack<Shape> undoHistory = new Stack();
    Stack<Shape> redoHistory = new Stack();

    Image image1 = new 
  Image("C:\\Users\\Mhamd\\Desktop\\stickers\\src\\resources\\imgbin_clicker-stickers- 
  telegram- 
  decal-vkontakte-png.png",100,100,false,false);
    Image image2 = new 
  Image("C:\\Users\\Mhamd\\Desktop\\stickers\\src\\resources\\favpng_sticker-decal-telegram- 
  emoticon-adhesive.png",100,100,false,false);
    Image image3 = new 
  Image("C:\\Users\\Mhamd\\Desktop\\stickers\\src\\resources\\favpng_donald-duck-telegram- 
  sticker.png",100,100,false,false);
    ImageView view1 = new ImageView(image1);
    view1.setFitHeight(80);
    view1.setPreserveRatio(true);
    ImageView view2 = new ImageView(image2);
    view2.setFitHeight(80);
    view2.setPreserveRatio(true);
    ImageView view3 = new ImageView(image3);
    view3.setFitHeight(80);
    view3.setPreserveRatio(true);

    /* ----------btns---------- */
    ToggleButton button1 = new ToggleButton();
    ToggleButton button2 = new ToggleButton();
    ToggleButton button3 = new ToggleButton();

    button1.setGraphic(view1);
    button2.setGraphic(view2);
    button3.setGraphic(view3);

    ToggleButton[] toolsArr = {button1, button2, button3};

    ToggleGroup tools = new ToggleGroup();

    for (ToggleButton tool : toolsArr) {
        tool.setMinWidth(90);
        tool.setToggleGroup(tools);
        tool.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    }


    Button undo = new Button("Undo");
    Button redo = new Button("Redo");
    Button save = new Button("Save");
    Button open = new Button("Open");
    Button createNew = new Button("Create New");

    Button[] basicArr = {save, open,createNew,undo,redo};

    for(Button btn : basicArr) {
        btn.setMinWidth(90);
        btn.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        btn.setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
        btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #666;");
    }
    save.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #80334d;");
    open.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #80334d;");
    createNew.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #80334d;");
    undo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #80334d;");
    redo.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #80334d;");

    VBox btns = new VBox(10);
    btns.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2, button3, open, save,createNew,undo,redo);
    btns.setPadding(new Insets(5));
    btns.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #999");
    btns.setPrefWidth(100);

    /* ----------Draw Canvas---------- */
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(1080, 790);
    GraphicsContext gc;
    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setLineWidth(1);

    canvas.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
        if(button1.isSelected()) {
            gc.drawImage(image1, e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        else if(button2.isSelected()) {
            gc.drawImage(image2,e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
        else if(button3.isSelected()) {
            gc.drawImage(image3,e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    });

    /*------- Create New Paint ------*/
    //Create
    createNew.setOnAction((e) ->{
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    });

    /*------- Save & Open ------*/
    // Open
    open.setOnAction((e)->{
        FileChooser openFile = new FileChooser();
        openFile.setTitle("Open File");
        File file = openFile.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                InputStream io = new FileInputStream(file);
                Image img = new Image(io);
                gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        }
    });

    // Save
    save.setOnAction((e)->{
        FileChooser savefile = new FileChooser();
        savefile.setTitle("Save File");

        File file = savefile.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(1080, 790);
                canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
                RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
                ImageIO.write(renderedImage, ".png", file);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error!");
            }
        }

    });

    /* ----------UNDO & REDO---------- */


    /* ----------STAGE & SCENE---------- */
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setLeft(btns);
    pane.setCenter(canvas);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1200, 800);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Stickers");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: @jewelsea I'm keeping the entire code so that everything would be clear

Comment: [mcve] please ..  mind the __M__! (f.i. redo/undo are unrelated as are visual gimmicks to the buttons) - nevertheless be certain to make it reproducible

Comment: I don't really understand your problem description. I'm interpreting it two different ways. (1) If you mean the file name does not end in `.png`, then note the extension does not determine the format of the file. For example, you could have a file whose extension is `.png` but internally the bytes are actually a PDF. (2) If you mean the actual bytes in the file are not in PNG format—though not sure how you manage to load it if this is the case—then does anything change if you use `"png"` instead of `".png"` when you call `ImageIO.write`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are trying to solve could be as simple as :

```
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final int CANVAS_SIZE = 200;
    private static final String FISH_IMAGE = "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/03/28/14104_animal_256x256.png";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Image image = new Image(FISH_IMAGE,100,100,false,false);
        Button save = new Button("Save");
        VBox btns = new VBox(save);

        /* ----------Draw Canvas---------- */
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(CANVAS_SIZE, CANVAS_SIZE);
        GraphicsContext gc  = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.drawImage(image, 50, 50);

        // Save
        save.setOnAction((e)->{
            FileChooser savefile = new FileChooser();
            savefile.setTitle("Save File");

            File file = savefile.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);
            System.out.println("is file null ? "+ file);
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(CANVAS_SIZE, CANVAS_SIZE);
                    canvas.snapshot(null, writableImage);
                    RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
                    ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Error!");
                }
            }
        });

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setLeft(btns);
        pane.setCenter(canvas);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This makes isolatng the problem and helping way easier.
To overwrite a PNG file you only have to select it with the filechooder.
To create a new file you need to type its name **and** its extension: `name.png` 
You can have the extension applied automatically by adding an `ExtensionFilter` to the `FileChooser`

```
FileChooser savefile = new FileChooser();
savefile.setTitle("Save File");
// Set extension filter
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files", "*.PNG");
savefile.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
```